# How to show achievements page using Android Google Play Services in custom language

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-games

I'm developing an app which uses Android Google Play Games. I have implemented an achievement system and just need to show the achievements page in the language selected by the user.

Here is the code I use to show achievements page:

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(getApiClient()), 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it is NOT possible. To avoid that, I had to develop my own UI to display them.